# Define function in x64dbg

Tags: dynamic-analysis, x64dbg

I am reversing a fairly complex app. In x64dbg (with xAnalyzer), is it possible to have custom function definitions?

A simple example would be to have a definition for `WinMain(hInstance, hPrevInstance, lpCmdLine, nCmdShow)`, that would show similar to this:

[image: Definition example]

I tried adding API definitions to `apis_def` in `xAnalyzer` but it did not work out.

Comment: You should be able to do it. xAnalyzer api's functions definition files are 100% customizables. Can you give more details about your issue? what files have you been editing and so on? Creator of xAnalyzer over here